# Gradle -How to use stable version for compile and a snapshot version of same dependency for testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, gradle, version

I need to use a stable version (e.g. 1.0) for compile purpose and and the same dependencies but with different version (2.0-SNAPSHOT) for test purpose. But I'm not able to do it.

I'm using SpringBoot 1.5.22.RELEASE

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'org.owasp.dependencycheck'

dependencies {
def saVersion = '1.0'

compile group: 'com.try.sdk', name: 'cl', version: "${saVersion}"
constraints {
    testImplementation("com.try.sdk:cl:2.0-SNAPSHOT")
} }
```

the gradle I provided is not complete but shows the part of code I need. Do you know how to fix it? As you can see I tried with testImplementation (and before with testCompile) but nothing fixed it.